# How to fill a Textbox on any website using an embeded webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have looked for a way to fill a Textbox on a website on a Windows form App that contains an embedded web browser(C# ).

Above task used to be very easy using Microsoft WebBrowser. But Microsoft stopped supporting it in VS 2019 and then completely removed it in VS 2022.

Please let me know if you know of a 3rd party web browser control to achieve this.

I have found Microsoft Webview. Does this one have the capability to put text in a text box of the webpage it loaded or it's only for viewing a webpage?

Comment: With WebView2, you can inject JavaScript for that. Before the HTML is rendered ([AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addscripttoexecuteondocumentcreatedasync), e.g., to install Event Listeners) or after, calling [ExecuteScriptAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync). You could have done this also with the old WebBrowser Control instead of using the COM object model